# LINQ TO SQL: Detect existing data

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I need LINQ code to be able to detect if an entry is input but the datum already exists in the table.

```
public Boolean CheckAssessment(String assessmentName)
{
    {
        SQL_TA_SCOREBOARDEntities1 d = new SQL_TA_SCOREBOARDEntities1();
        Assessment A_List = new Assessment();
        {

            var qry2 = from b in contxt.View_Assessment
                       where b.AssessmentName == assessmentName
                       select b;


            if (qry2 = assessmentName.ToString())
            {
                return true;                         
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Where assessmentName is the value of the textbox in the a separate C# class.

```
Boolean i;
i = TAClass.CheckAssessment(txtAssessmentName.ToString());

if (i == true)
{
    Label2.Text = "Assessment name already exists.";
}
```

Comment: Your code can be improved a lot as you can see in my answer. But, just to make it clear for you, your code would not work because of two reasons: 1) the linq can return more than one result (you should use the `FirstOrDefault` extension) and 2) you need to select `b.AssessmentName` in linq code, otherwise it will return an object for you (and not a string)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct way is to use Any() extension method. Any() will generate optimized query and will return true as soon as the query found the record.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534338.aspx

So, in your CheckAssessment method, you can do like this:

```
        return (from b in assessments
                where b.AssessmentName == assessmentName
                select b).Any();
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `Count()` extension to check if there are any matching records:

```
public bool CheckAssessment(string assessmentName)
{
    return (from b in contxt.View_Assessment
        where b.AssessmentName == assessmentName
        select b).Count() > 0;
}
```

UPDATE: just for your knowledge, your code could work this way:

```
public Boolean CheckAssessment(String assessmentName)
{
  {
    SQL_TA_SCOREBOARDEntities1 d = new SQL_TA_SCOREBOARDEntities1();
    Assessment A_List = new Assessment();
    {

        var qry2 = (from b in contxt.View_Assessment
                   where b.AssessmentName == assessmentName
                   select b.AssessmentName).FirstOrDefault();


        if (qry2 = assessmentName.ToString())
        {
            return true;                         
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Just one more comment, always that you have something like:

```
if (a) { return true; } else {return false;}
```

you can replace by

```
 return a;
```

Comment: Code-only answers don't give the full picture.  Helps to have an explanation to go with the code.

Comment: Thanks for the helpful comment. I will remember that. And thank you for the edition.